# Change the name of the class being serialized in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I can map incoming class names by using a `SerializationBinder` and overriding the `BindToType` method, but I found no way of changing the name of the class in the serialization process. Is it possible at all??

**EDIT:**

I am referring to the serialization using the `System.Runtime.Serialization`, and not the `System.Xml.Serialization`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe to me why you'd want to do that? I often find that if there isn't a function/method for what I'm trying to do then I'm missing a much simpler solution or I'm just trying to do something odd.

Comment: I want to do that to make the process of serialization and deserialization independent of the class name, so that if I rename the class, or change the namespace of the class, the serialization and deserialization wouldn't change at all.

Comment: What type of Serialization are you performing? Binary? Xml? Other?

Comment: @silky: It is the serialization kind that uses formatters, not Xml.

Comment: @Miguel Is it possible to switch to XML? This will make your life significantly easier. The Binary serialisation method is not made to handle changes to your object model.

Comment: I found a way to do it!!! I didn't want to go Xml serialization anyway, because it is not very flexible, the ISerializable interface is a lot more flexible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out that I can use the `SerializationInfo` object that comes in the `GetObjectData` function, and change the `AssemblyName` and `FullTypeName` properties, so that when I deserialize I can use a `SerializationBinder` to map the custom assembly and type-name back to a valid type. Here is a semple:

**Serializable class:**

```
[Serializable]
class MyCustomClass : ISerializable
{
    string _field;
    void MyCustomClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        this._field = info.GetString("PropertyName");
    }
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AssemblyName = "MyCustomAssemblyIdentifier";
        info.FullTypeName = "MyCustomTypeIdentifier";
        info.AddValue("PropertyName", this._field);
    }
}
```

**SerializationBinder:**

```
public class MyBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        if (assemblyName == "MyCustomAssemblyIdentifier")
            if (typeName == "MyCustomTypeIdentifier")
                return typeof();
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Serialization code:**

```
var fs = GetStream();
BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
f.Binder = new MyBinder();
var obj = (MyCustomClass)f.Deserialize(fs);
```

**Deserialization code:**

```
var fs = GetStream();
MyCustomClass obj = GetObjectToSerialize();
BinaryFormatter f = new BinaryFormatter();
f.Deserialize(fs, obj);
```

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if I follow you, but you could use XmlTypeAttribute. You can then easily retrieve its values through reflection.

```
[XmlType(Namespace = "myNamespaceThatWontChange",
TypeName = "myClassThatWontChange")]
public class Person
{
   public string Name;
}
```

Check this out:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmltypeattribute%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: But this is XmlSerialization, I am talking about the serialization that uses the SerializableAttribute and ISerializable interface.

Comment: Islam Ibrahim's answer is 'the' answer then (as far as I know).

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with attributes:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRoot("xmlName")]
public Class ClassName
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a surrogate + surrogate selector. That together with a binder on the deserialization should do the trick.

Comment: This is very interesting, but it is not what I was looking for. I found out that I can use the `SerializationInfo` object of the `GetObjectData` and change both `AssemblyName` and `FullTypeName` properties.

Comment: This is rather dangerous in the way that you may need to serialize instances indifferent contexts. i.e. data transfer between tiers, cloning, peristance etc.  If you do go this route, be sure to specify the streaming context. 

(example)
formatter.Context = new System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContextStates.CrossMachine);
 
and be aware also that you will be tied to the binder that you name the items for.